# Desabilitar o botao "Fechar" de um form

Tags: vb.net

Alguém sabe como eu desabilito o botão "Fechar" ("X") de um form no VB.net?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca isso no codebehind do seu form,

```
Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
Get
    Dim param As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
    param.ClassStyle = param.ClassStyle Or &H200
    Return param
End Get
End Property
```

Fonte: [aqui](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/354393/Disable-Close-Button-X-in-the-Vb-Net)

Comment: Era isso mesmo que eu queria, muito obrigado!